# IP incorrect when making curl request from the same server

Tags: .htaccess, curl

I have a user A with IP **AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA**, this user needs to access a directory of an other user B (with IP **BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB**) with CURL on the same server (Directadmin/CentOS/IP CCC). This directory of this user is locked with HTAccess. Normally for outside users I would open the directory in the HTAccess by adding his/her IP address to the HTAccess file:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
</Limit>
```

The request from user A doesn't go through (403). I've made a test.php on user B:

```
<?
echo json_encode($_SERVER, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When cURLing to this file from user A:

```
curl -XPOST https://example.com/test.php --dns-ipv4-addr AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
```

i get the following result:

```
"SERVER_ADDR": “BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB”,
"REMOTE_ADDR": “BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB”,
```

***So the issue: When cURLing from the same server, User B reports its own IP address as the external party (SERVER_ADDR and REMOTE_ADDR are the same).*** I would obviously like the result to be:

```
"SERVER_ADDR": “BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB”,
"REMOTE_ADDR": “AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA”,
```

So my IP limiting will then work as expected. I would also like to add that if i add **BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB** to the htaccess, the request does come in. Also, making a request from my computer, the ip address is also reported correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-dns-ipv4-addr` is only the address to be used for DNS requests. It's not used for the actual request. Try `--interface` instead:

```
curl -XPOST https://example.com/test.php --interface aa.aa.aa.aa
```

Comment: Looks promising. Will test and have results within the hour!

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!!